# Is it possible insert image to a code comment?

Tags: c#, ide, comments

My question is probably an insane idea, however, it's very valuable when I write code for educational purpose.

Especially when the code is relevant to math and physics, images inserted in comment are more convenient and articulated.

Until now, I can't find a way succeed to insert a true image into comment, not C# nor python or any other common programming language or IDE.

Using tools that convert images to ASCII image is a workaround but less precise.

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Format the code using [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) for presentation to students. Embed useful images that way.

Comment: See http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e216ec81-730b-4022-8305-25c39eb1f820

Comment: In some scenarios, deliver code directly to students is needed. Ppt, blog post or a LaTeX formatted article is not necessary for just one more image.

Comment: 12 years and not yet an IDE managing this feature natively. I have been programming for 35+ years and it is the one I miss more in tools like PyCharm.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an example here that extend the Visual Studio 2010 editor: [Image Insertion](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/793d16d0-235a-439a-91df-4ce7c721df12) (but it's tied to Visual Studio, not a generic solution)

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is unfortunately not what I call a modern IDE...

Comment: This is not an agnostic solution: the question is not mentionning a particular IDE. What about rewarding @PanthersFan92 solution?

Comment: @MartinDelille - well, this is an old question and an old answer, reward the answer you think deserves it.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, you can use the "Memeful Comments" extension. It allows links to local files: `// <image src="a.png"/>`.

Comment: Thanks man memeful comments is perfect :D

Answer (score 5):

For Python you can use Google Colab.
Inside a text-block you can write something like:

```
![Alt text](https://someurl.com/image.png).
```

Example:
[image]

For C# you can try this plug-in:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MsBishop.ImageComments

Comment: I like your solution because it is more agnostic that you described it: the markdown `!` prefix means that we are dealing with an image and most of the IDE support control click to open an external link. Modern IDE should all have this plugin though!

Comment: thanks for the VS plugin reference, it's unfortunate it doesn't work for VS 2019! :( there's a year old ticket open on it without feedback from the author...

Answer (score 4):

I politely disagree with @thekip reply. IDE is not just the editor, but a full set of tools, and thank God code editors has been evolving from the old times. That’s why:

Eons ago I was amazed with the AMOS developer tool for old AMIGA computers, that had the fold/unfold capability you can see now in many code editors, and during many years I was asking myself why Borland and Microsoft tools didn’t had it. It’s clear that information should not be always at the same level.

Code editors already had automatic text styling, to see different kind of reserved words or comments in different colors, allow auto indentation, and so.

Comments in code is an a topic in discussion out there, with some people defending that maintaining them under minims is the way to follow, arguing that they are usually not maintained by developers as they change code. People like me disagree with that, having in mind that comments are part of the code.

Not always all comments have the same importance, and 2020 tools should provide something better than UPERCASE and a bunch of dash separators ----------

Allow different font size, bold and italic in comments is the “must have” we will have again some eons later, and sometimes an image diagram in the same code could save you many time of search in the appropriate project documentation. Google Collab and other Jupyter tools seems to finally understood that.

All this should not replace project documentation through other tools, of course but, hey, do other people’s lives easier.

> *Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.*
>
> ***John Woods***

@Simon Mourier reply for Visual Studio, rocks!

Answer (score 3):

Literate Programming tools work this way; you basically use TeX or something to write the code, then run a preprocessor which extracts the code snippets into an intermediate source file. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming

Comment: thanks @tripleee. Woot, I have never known literate programming. The wiki is a good start for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Using Sandcastle**

Each SHFB project is it's own container for *everything* seen in the documentation project.  When it's compiled, the (program project's") XML doc is pulled into SHFB to be put into the document.

If you want to show images in the top section of the class documentation, you must add the image to the SHFB project and refer to that image from the code comment.  See Problem 2...

**Problem 1:**

*"I can't get an image to show from a conceptual topic using the 'image' tag"*

1. Make sure to use the proper XML markup similar to this:

   ```
   <section>
     <content>        
       <mediaLink>
          <image xlink:href="MyMainImage"/>
       </mediaLink>
     </content>
   </section>
   ```
2. Notice that the Href (above) **doesn't have the file type** associated,
   this is **because Sandcastle wants the ID** instead.
3. Add the image to the project **using the default media folder**. Or, if you want you can create your own folder e.g Images.
4. Go to properties page of the image and set  Build action to **Image**.
   When you use an "image" tag, SHFB  only uses the **Image ID** found in the properties page, seen in the HREF above.
5. Recompile the project and open up the CHM file and you will see the
       image.

**Problem 2:**

*"I cannot get an Image to show using Code commenting XML markup in the programming project".*

1. In the summary section of the code comment, the markup can look like
   this:

   ```
   /// <summary>   
   /// <remarks><img src="\Images\MyImage.PNG"/></remarks>
   /// </summary>
   ```
2. Note that the src attribute **does** contain the file type. It also must correctly identify the folder that your SHFB project has for that image.
3. After adding that image to the SHFB right click on it and change the "Build Action" property to **Content**

Happy coding and documenting! 
Thanks goes to Eric W.

Keywords: 
SHFB Cannot Add Image 
Sandcastle Help File Builder Conceptual Topic Images 
Code Commenting Images 
CHM File Images
How to add an image in XML Code Commenting C#

Answer (score 2):

I found [Jupyter Notebooks](https://jupyter.org/) very valuable for teaching and used them with Python. They let you combine text, images and code.

Microsoft [announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-with-juypter-notebooks-is-here-preview-1/) Jupyter Notebooks for .NET core and it is now in Preview in the [.NET Interactive](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive) repo.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Idea and wanted to check if someone already shared it.

I just did it one way: Wordpad -> wrote code with an image between /*  */ and saved as text document: images removed. just an empty comment zone remaining.

Of course, many interesting possibilities are missing from such an editor.
But all that is needed would be to allow a better suited one to include images.

It could greatly speed up the understanding of code if visual elements are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use a free image hosting like http://imgur.com and insert image link to code comment?

Then the only problem for a student would be to copypaste link to browser from any IDE. Quite easy though.

Maybe some IDEs have the ability to "underline" links so that you can click it instead of copypasting.

Answer (score 1):

Since I always wanted to have this solution myself, I just created a VS Code extension. I hope it meets your needs, although VS Code doesn't allow inline images. But I found the tooltip solution even more practical:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgiesen.image-comments

Answer (score 0):

Actually,you can always include the link of the image but cannot add an image to the comment of the code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're using the wrong tool for your problem. An IDE is a 'development' environment so it's not very important to have complete control over styling.

I would use something else (like LaTeX, see the comment) for you presentation.

Comment: Thanks @thekip. Sometimes, code is good enough to show to students. But publish a blog or a paper just for one image is waste of time. That's the reason I ask this question.

Comment: I gave you my bounty but afterward the markdown link solution from @PanthersFan92 is the best in my opinion